spring-vault-core KeyValueDelegate mountInfo caching issue
I'm using spring-vault-core 3.1.1 with Spring Boot 3.2.6. My service interacts with Vault during startup to fetch certain entities and later accesses Vault upon the first gRPC request to the service.
Here's the problem: when Vault is temporarily unavailable, the KeyValueDelegate class sets an empty string "" as the mount path in its internal mountInfo cache. This results in an exception being thrown:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path must not be empty.
Even when Vault becomes available again, the cached empty path in mountInfo is reused, and the service remains unable to connect to Vault until it is restarted. This leads to a persistent failure state, forcing us to restart pods during health check failures, which is risky and may disrupt active requests during a graceful shutdown.
I’ve tried the following approaches:

Overriding getMountInfo() — Not feasible since plenty of final/private/default.
Configuration changes — I couldn’t find any documented way to prevent caching of invalid paths or clear the mountInfo cache on error.

My questions:
Has anyone faced a similar issue or found a solution/workaround for this caching behavior in KeyValueDelegate?
Is there a way to configure Vault paths at startup to prepopulate the mountInfo cache with correct values?
Are there any updates in later versions of spring-vault-core (e.g., 3.1.2 or beyond) that address this issue?
Additional context:
Current workaround: Restart pods on health check failure (including Vault availability checks).
Environment: Spring Boot 3.2.6, Spring Vault 3.1.1, running in Kubernetes.
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!
